# Remove the strikethrough on legend symbols for line charts?

Tags: highcharts

I am using the predefined symbols for highcharts on a line chart, and would like to only have the symbol show. I do not want the line to show on there as well. I see that it is possible for a bubble chart, but when I change the chart type from bubble to line, the strikethrough appears: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/bubble-symbol/. Any thoughts on to how I could combat this? Thanks in advance!

```
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Bubbles with symbols'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [97, 36, 79],
            [94, 74, 60],
            [68, 76, 58],
            [64, 87, 56],
            [68, 27, 73],
            [74, 99, 42],
            [7, 93, 87],
            [51, 69, 40],
            [38, 23, 33],
            {
                x: 57,
                y: 0,
                z: 31,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'triangle',
                    lineColor: 'red',
                    fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: 'Individual marker'
                }
            }
        ],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
        name: 'Square'
    }, {
        data: [
            [25, 10, 87],
            [2, 75, 59],
            [11, 54, 8],
            [86, 55, 93],
            [5, 3, 58],
            [90, 63, 44],
            [91, 33, 17],
            [97, 3, 56],
            [15, 67, 48],
            [54, 25, 81]
        ],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'diamond'
        },
        name: 'Diamond'
    }, {
        data: [
            [47, 47, 21],
            [20, 12, 4],
            [6, 76, 91],
            [38, 30, 40],
            [57, 98, 64],
            [61, 17, 10],
            [83, 60, 13],
            [67, 78, 75],
            [64, 12, 10],
            [30, 77, 82]
        ],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/earth.svg)'
        },
        name: 'Earth'
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the scatter series type to achieve it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8gpnx90v/

```
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },
```

API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/scatter-chart

Comment: Hello, thanks for sharing! However, I need it to be a line chart. Would you happen to know any other way to achieve this?

Comment: setting lineWidth to 0 disables line in the line chart series and makes that markers only left. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8nvkud6p/ But the visual output is the same like while using the scatter series

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying! Is there some way to have the line chart connect while also only having the symbols themselves in the legend? I do not want a scatter chart, and I do not want it to be a line chart that looks like a scatter chart. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hsf5Lpnd/ I used the linkedTo feature to attach the series to the dummy scatter series (to get the symbol without the line to the legend)  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late answer but if you set symbolWidth to the same value as the radius of your symbols it will hide the lines in the legend:

```
  legend: {
      layout: 'horizontal',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      symbolWidth: 6
  },  
  plotOptions: {
      line: {
        marker: {
          symbol: 'circle',
          radius: 6
        }
      }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                            legend: {
                                    useHTML: true,
                                    enabled: true,

                                itemStyle: {
                                    font: '9pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                                    activecolor: '#CCC',
                                    'font-weight': 'bold',
                                    'text-decoration': 'none'          /** <---  **/
                                }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should arrage code.